# How to measure time of handshake in C++ Curl with OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, curl, openssl, handshake

I have some options for curl:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1;
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_DATA, this);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, SslContextFunction);
...
```

How to get callback from curl when handshake will be ended?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using OpenSSL, when your `SslContextFunction` is called, use `SSL_CTX_set_info_callback` to establish a callback for various events that occur inside the SSL context. One of the events will be `SSL_CB_HANDSHAKE_DONE`.